# Making arrow function generic

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this function that return an array of N items

```
const result = (length: number, func) => {
  return Array.from({ length }, func);
};

interface MyItemType {
    data1: string,
    data2: string,
    data3: string,
}

export const item = (): MyItemType => {
  return {
    data1: 'data1',
    data2: 'data2',
    data3: 'data3',
  };
};

let a = result(2, item);
```

here is [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=28&pln=19&pc=1#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2AJwKYwK4BsEF5gAoNkoBzOACwC5go0BbAI2UQBpgAzNKMKgQygE8AlMGwA%20YAG8AUKFAo4aRFGABBRIh78AdG0QRaeCcEIlywAL6sOXQQG4Zoc-YcgAllDhM2PMMmABZfgBJT1oAFX4ABz9pWVkAEx44HgBGKnhEd2JmFzjE5IAmdLhMkhy40HyeAGZi0uzc8ylc5AAPSIhEBEhYBFdQkXxBKkCQ5HCovzFJXJB5RWVYiuAqtOAAclX18uWqoo297dnKpJqqTdPqo4qnRudQQgQeQZR0LDwC1n7xuyA)

I want to change my code to be generic so I can call my result funciton like that:

```
   let a = <MyItemType[]>result(2, item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `func` parameter return a generic

```
const result = <T,>(length: number, func: () => T) => {
  return Array.from({ length }, func);
};
```

Comment: how the calling code would look like? this does not work `let a = <MyItemType[]>result(2, <MyItemType>item);`

Comment: You don't need to add the type with `<MyItemType[]>` since it's going to be inferred by typescript. Just call it like this: `result(2, item);`

Comment: got an error: `Argument of type '(_: any, index: number) => MyItemType' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => MyItemType'`

Comment: You can call it  like this `result<MyItemType[]>(2, item);` too

Comment: how did you call it?

Comment: Just tried  `result<MyItemType>(2, item);`  and `result<MyItemType[]>(2, item);`  does not work, still errors 

`Argument of type '(_: any, index: number) => MyItemType' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => MyItemType'

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. TS playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGMHsDsGcBdQCcCmsCuAbRBeUAKTFaAc3gAsAuUadAWwCMUkAaUAM3WnAEpQcAfKADeAKBChJqeOiTRQAQSRIAhgE8AdOySQ6+YaCKkKoAL5tO3HgG5xYU7bugA+tRXQ1bAJbQAJigAPalpGZlEnKDhEVAxsflAAHgAVFgFCYjIqGnomVg4ucGp8V1B3T1AffyDs0KQ+QVAk+qExCSkUGTlFZXUtHT0DI0yzCwKbJwdwyIRkNCxcRJS0oYpgnOZR7iLmxp2xds75JVVNbV19QwyTc3yrW0nRH3hmdhVwFFAAWTUASWe6JJqAAOH32klAvhU8BUAEZqAgkD4SCxROCIVCVAAmeHwRGkFFoyHQgDMOLxyNEpimMBmXn+8XwPGo3z+KABwI+DTB0lk8jBkiJsOoAHJBTDhQTwYLsaBRRjMRLUVKMaTZYLiYrJJMHkRECp4jF5vhMd5-uNRNNIEQNJhICR8CobEA